# How to determine which artifact contains a class using Maven Central?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-rest

I have been looking for the Spring RestTemplate artifact on Maven Central and have only found the Android version.

What method(s) can be used to determine which artifact contains this class using Maven Central?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Central, you can use the `fc:` tag to search for a fully-qualified classname, such as [`org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate). The search results show that it's available in two artifacts, `spring-android-rest-template` and `spring-web`. This indicates that `spring-web` is indeed the artifact that contains that class.

(I believe the rationale for including it in one artifact is that the RestTemplate depends on a large number of annotations and similar classes provided by the Web artifact. If you think there's a good reason for splitting them, the Spring 5 development effort is underway, and you could open a ticket on the [Spring JIRA](https://jira.spring.io) to separate them.)

Comment: Does not work on their new-and-improved site: https://central.sonatype.dev/search, Dadburnit.